# Merge/Discard overlapping words

Tags: python, ruby, perl, bash

I want to merge strings (words) that are similar (string is within other string).

```
 word
 wor 
 words
 wormhole
 hole
```

Would make:

```
words
wormhole
```

As `wor` overlaps with: `word`, `words`, `wormhole` -`wor` is discarded;
`word` overlaps with: `words` - `word` is discarded;
`hole` overlaps with: `wormhole` - `hole` is discarded;
but `words`, `wormhole` don't overlap - so they stay.
How can I do this?

**Edit**
My solution is:

```
while read a
do  
   grep $a FILE | 
   awk 'length > m { m = length; a = $0 } END { print a }'
done < FILE | 
sort -u
```

But I don't know if it would't cause troubles with large datasets.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: This is pretty vague.

Comment: This specific example is simple to solve: Sort the list of all words in ascending order. If a word is a substring of the next word, discard current word; move on otherwise. However, this only covers words that start with each other. For a general solution where word A contains word B, you'd probably have to go quadratic.

Comment: It should overlap anywhere in the string.

Comment: @Poe You probably ought to remove **holes** to make it less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that sorting the words longest-to-shortest, we can then step through the sorted list only once, matching only against kept words.  I'm poor at algorithmic analysis, but this makes sense to me and I *think* the performance would be good.  It also seems to work, assuming the order of the kept words doesn't matter:

```
words = ['word', 'wor', 'words', 'wormhole', 'hole']
keepers = []

words.sort_by(&:length).reverse.each do |word|
  keepers.push(word) if ! keepers.any?{|keeper| keeper.include?(word)}
end

keepers
# => ["wormhole", "words"]
```

If the order of the kept words does matter, it would be pretty easy to modify this to account for that.  One option would simply be:

```
words & keepers
# => ["words", "wormhole"]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby:

```
list = %w[word wor words wormhole]

list.uniq
.tap{|a| a.reverse_each{|e| a.delete(e) if (a - [e]).any?{|x| x.include?(e)}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a sufficiently long list of words, any nested loop over the words is going to be painfully slow.  This is how I'd do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp 'read_file';
chomp( my @words = read_file('/usr/share/dict/words') );

my %overlapped;
for my $word (@words) {
    $word =~ /(.*)(?{++$overlapped{$1}})(*FAIL)/;
    --$overlapped{$word};
}

print "$_\n" for grep ! $overlapped{$_}, @words;
```

It could perhaps be improved with Darshan Computing's suggestion of processing words longest to shortest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hash to count the substrings of your list of words:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %seen;                   # seen substrings
my @words;                  # original list
while (<DATA>) {            # read a new substring
    chomp;
    push @words, $_;        # store the original
    while (length) {        # while a substring remains
            $seen{$_}++;    # increase its counter
            chop;           # shorten the substring
    }
}

# All original words with count == 1 are the merged list
my @merged = grep $seen{$_} == 1, @words;

say for @merged;

__DATA__
w
word
wor
words
wormhole
hole
holes
```

**Output:**

```
words
wormhole
holes
```

Of course, you will need to compensate for case, punctuation and whitespace, as hash keys are exact, and the key `Foo` is different from the key `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with `any`/`all`:

```
>>> lis = ['word','wor', 'words', 'wormhole']
#all
>>> [x for x in lis if all(x not in y for y in lis if y != x)]
['words', 'wormhole']
#any
>>> [x for x in lis if not any(x in y for y in lis if y != x)]
['words', 'wormhole']
```

You can also use [marisa_trie](https://github.com/kmike/marisa-trie) here :

```
>>> import marisa_trie
>>> lis = ['word','wor', 'words', 'wormhole', 'hole', 'holes']
>>> def trie(lis):
        trie = marisa_trie.Trie(lis)
        return [x for x in lis if len(trie.keys(unicode(x))) ==1 ]
... 
>>> trie(lis)
['words', 'wormhole', 'holes']
```

Answer (score 1):

amon's suggestion of...

> Sort the list of all words in ascending order. If a word is a
>   substring of the next word, discard current word; move on otherwise.

...would require O(n log n) for the sort, and I'm not sure about the time complexity of Ashwini's solution, but it looks to be more than O(n log n).

I think this is an O(n) solution...

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = ['word', 'wor', 'words', 'wormhole']

infinite_defaultdict = lambda: defaultdict(infinite_defaultdict)

mydict = infinite_defaultdict()
for word in words:
    d = mydict
    for char in word:
        d = d[char]

result = []
for word in words:
    d = mydict
    for char in word:
        d = d[char]
    if not d:
        result.append(word)

print result
```

...which prints...

```
['words', 'wormhole']
```

---

**Update**

> But I don't know if it would't cause troubles with large datasets.

For comparison, using 10,000 words from `/usr/share/dict/words`, this takes about 70 milliseconds of CPU time, whereas Ashwini's takes about 11 seconds.

---

**Update 2**

Okay. The original question read as if words could only overlap at the start, but if they can overlap anywhere, this code won't work. I think any algorithm which could do that would have a worst-case complexity of O(n²).

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question as

> Given a word list, we want to remove all those words that are substrings of other words.

Here is a general Perl solution:

```
sub weed_out {
  my @out;
  WORD:
  while (my $current = shift) {
    for (@_) {
      # skip $current word if it's a substring of any other word
      next WORD if -1 != index $_, $current;
    }
    push @out, $current;
  }
  return @out;
}
```

Note that we `shift` from the `@_` argument array, thus the inner loop gets shorter each time.

If we encounter a word that is a substring of the `$current` word while doing the inner loop, we actually can remove it via `splice`:

```
  WORD:
  while (my $current = shift) {
    for (my $i = 0; ; $i++) {
      last unless $i <= $#_; # loop condition must be here
      # remove the other word if it's a substring of $current
      splice(@_, $i, 1), redo if -1 != index $current, $_[$i];
      # skip $current word if it's a substring of any other word
      next WORD if -1 != index $_[$i], $current;
    }
    push @out, $current;
  }
```

But I'd rather benchmark that “optimization”.

This can be easily embedded into a shell script if needed:

```
$ perl - <<'END' FILE
my @words = <>;
chomp(@words);
WORD: while (my $current = shift @words) {
  for (@words) {
    # skip $current word if it's a substring of any other word
    next WORD if -1 != index $_, $current;
  }
  print "$current\n";
}
END
```

Comment: your first solution fails on ("AB", "A"); the second one generates warnings, not sure what you are trying to do in it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    a[$1]++
    next
} 
{
    for (x in a) { 
        if (index ($1,x) == 0) { 
            a[x] 
        } 
        else { 
            delete a[x]
            a[$1] 
        } 
    }
}
END {
    for (x in a) {
        print x 
    }
}' inputFile inputFile
```

#### Test:

```
inputFile of:

word
wormholes
wor
words
wormhole
hole

Returns:

words
wormholes
```

Answer (score 1):

a bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
dict="word wor words wormhole hole "
uniq=()

sort_by_length() {
    for word; do
        printf "%d %s\n" ${#word} "$word"
    done | sort -n | cut -d " " -f2-
}
set -- $(sort_by_length $dict)

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    word=$1
    shift
    found=false
    for w;  do
        if [[ $w == *"$word"* ]]; then
            found=true
            break
        fi
    done
    if ! $found; then
        uniq+=($word)
    fi
done

echo "${uniq[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Lengthy perl oneliner,

```
perl -nE 'chomp;($l,$p)=($_,0); @w=grep{ $p=1 if /$l/; $p|| $l!~/$_/} @w; $p or push @w,$l}{say for @w' file
```